# Execute Func with generic type which should return a long value

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method with a `Func<T, long>` as parameter. I want to call that method like this:

```
Write(x => x.Id, "Some info");
```

The method looks like the following. The problem I have is inside that method. I don't know how to execute the function to get the `long` value.

```
public void Write<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, long> func, string info)
{
    var id = func(); // Doesn't work, func() needs an argument...
}
```

How does this work? How can I execute the function?

Comment: Well pass the instance of TEntity as argument. Otherwise, which "Id" you are going to read?

Comment: @Evk If you mean `func(TEntity)`, then that doesn't work. ***TEntity is a type, which is not valid in the given context***.

Comment: No I mean instance. Say TEntity is some YourType and you have an instance of YourType (var x = new YourType() {Id = 1}). Pass that to your function > var id = func(x). Just think about Id of **what** you are trying to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it doesn't work, you need n argument. Solution depends on what are you actuyll going to do.

1) You could just give TEntity as a parameter:

```
public void Write<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, long> func, TEntity entity, string info)
{
    var id = func(entity);
}
```

2) If this function is inside of TEntity class you could call it with this argument:

```
class TEntity
{
  public void Write<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, long> func, string info)
  {
      var id = func(this);
  }
}
```

3) Perhaps you don't need any TEntity to get an Id, in that case rewrite your paramter as a func without arguments:

```
public void Write<TEntity>(Func<long> func, string info)
{
    var id = func();
}
```